# css background color child not displaying

Tags: css, nested, background-color

I'm playing around with responsive grids but I'm having trouble getting the background-color to appear for nested elements.

My HTML and CSS are here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ro196bjr/9/

```
<body>  
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4 col-m-6 responsive-margin-bottom">
            <div class="box primary">
                <h1>Primary Box</h1>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- 25% -->
          <div class="col-8 col-m-6">
            <div class="box secondary">
                <h1>Secondary Box</h1>
                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- 75% -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
}  

/*-------------Layout------------- */


#container {
}

/*----Grid---- */
.grid-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    /* For tablets: */
    .col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 950px) {
    /* For desktop: */
    .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}

/*---- Box---- */

.box{
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}

.box .primary{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #74a57f;
}

.box .secondary{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #077187;
}
```

I've tried adding in overflow: auto; to the grid-container but that doesn't seem to help. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any space between .box and .primary. Having a space in between means the `primary class` is a descendant of `box class` but it is not so. They both refer to the same container class so remove the space between them, you can make use of `.box.primary or just .primary` and the same criteria for secondary as well.

`.box.primary` refers to the container having both box and primary class.

`.primary` refers to the container that has atleast primary class.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
}  

/*-------------Layout------------- */


#container {
}

/*----Grid---- */
.grid-container {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
 float: left;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    /* For tablets: */
    .col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 950px) {
    /* For desktop: */
    .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}

/*---- Box---- */

.box{
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}

.box.primary{
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #74a57f;
}

.box.secondary{
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #077187;
}
```

```html
<body> 
 <div class="grid-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 col-m-6 responsive-margin-bottom">
   <div class="box primary">
    <h1>Primary Box</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
   </div>
    </div> <!-- 25% -->
    <div class="col-8 col-m-6">
   <div class="box secondary">
    <h1>Secondary Box</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
   </div>
    </div> <!-- 75% -->
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing it in a proper way because you are writing `.box .primary` as well as `.box .secondry` with a **space between** `.box` and `.primary`/ `.secondry`, this is like you want to target the element that comes as a child for `.box` but in fact, the element you want to style contains both classes.

So the proper way is just to remove the space between the two classes to tell the browser that you want to style an element which has both classes.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
}  

/*-------------Layout------------- */


#container {
}

/*----Grid---- */
.grid-container {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
 float: left;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    /* For tablets: */
    .col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 950px) {
    /* For desktop: */
    .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}

/*---- Box---- */

.box{
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}

.box.primary{ /*no spaces between the two classes*/
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #74a57f;
}

.box.secondary{ /*no spaces between the two classes*/
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #077187;
}
```

```html
<body> 
 <div class="grid-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 col-m-6 responsive-margin-bottom">
   <div class="box primary">
    <h1>Primary Box</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
   </div>
    </div> <!-- 25% -->
    <div class="col-8 col-m-6">
   <div class="box secondary">
    <h1>Secondary Box</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
   </div>
    </div> <!-- 75% -->
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Check the updated [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ro196bjr/10/).